# Run Python script in Django website by clicking a submit button

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, django

I have a Django website. Once data is uploaded on this website, I want to run my Python script that would upload data to a MySql table and do some basic cleaning.
I have created the codes, say `data_upload.py`. that can do the same once any CSV file is placed in a specified folder.
Using the Django tutorials and answers on Stack Overflow I have created a website that can take contacts and through which you can upload data.
Now I want to built an application that starts with clicking a button. After the user clicks the button I would like to start my script `data_upload.py` .
How can I do this? I am willing to use jQuery and HTML/CSS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a view function which runs your data_upoad.py.  Assign it to a url in urls.py.  Then you can create a link (or a button I guess) which will invoke that view